# how to order reservedcapacitygroupInstance

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

we ordered ReservedCapacityGroup.

thanks to [how to order SoftLayer_Virtual_ReservedCapacityGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52660569/how-to-order-softlayer-virtual-reservedcapacitygroup).

and we tried to order ReservedCapacityGroupInstance.

- used IBM Cloud's Family Size type product(package-id : 835) & preset-id(293)
- used Virtual Guest's parameters

> - reservedCapacityGroup
> - reservedCapacityGroupFlag
> - reservedCapacityGroupInstance

But we failed to order instance. Ordered Server is not ReservedCapacityGroupInstance and is just normal virtual server.

```
{"parameters": [
    {
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order",
      "orderContainers": [
        {
          "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
          "location": "1555995",
          "packageId": 835,
          "quantity": 1,
          "presetId": 293,
          "virtualGuests": [
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest",
              "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
                "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component"
              },
              "domain": "rci.com",
              "hostname": "ReservedGroupIns-02",
              "primaryNetworkComponent": {
                "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Network_Component"
              },
              "reservedCapacityGroup": {
                "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_ReservedCapacityGroup",
                "id": 8201
              },
              "reservedCapacityGroupFlag": true,
              "reservedCapacityGroupInstance": {
                "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_ReservedCapacityGroup_Instance",
                "guestId": 63236601,
                "id": 8601
              }
            }
          ],
          "useHourlyPricing": true,
          "prices": [
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 13945
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 273
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 55
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 58
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 203971
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 204931
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 2202
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 21
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 1800
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 57
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 418
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 905
            },
            {
              "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price",
              "id": 420
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

additionally, I checked reservedcapacity information.

```
https://IBM_ID:IBM_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_ReservedCapacityGroup/8201/Instances.json
```

result

```
{
    "createDate": "",
    "guestId": 63236601,
    "id": 8601,
    "modifyDate": null,
    "reservedCapacityGroupId": 8201,
    "reservedCapacityGroup": {
        "accountId": 12345,
        "backendRouterId": 667615,
        "createDate": "2018-10-11T16:57:36+09:00",
        "id": 8201,
        "modifyDate": null,
        "name": "test",
        "instances": [
            null
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To order a ReservedCapacityGroupIncance you going to need to add  "reservedCapacityId" parameter in order body JSON structure. Furthermore, prices for the processor, ram, and disk are not necessary, you can use the below body JSON structure:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order",
      "orderContainers": [
        {
          "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
          "location": "1555995",
          "packageId": 835,
          "quantity": 1,
          "presetId": 293,
          "reservedCapacityId": 8601,
          "virtualGuests": [
            {
              "domain": "rci.com",
              "hostname": "ReservedGroupIns-02"
            }
          ],
          "useHourlyPricing": true,
          "prices": [
            {
              "id": 13945
            },
            {
              "id": 273
            },
            {
              "id": 55
            },
            {
              "id": 58
            },
            {
              "id": 21
            },
            {
              "id": 1800
            },
            {
              "id": 57
            },
            {
              "id": 418
            },
            {
              "id": 905
            },
            {
              "id": 420
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```