# The Virtual guests In Reserved Capacity isn't shown

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

we are checking API([how to order SoftLayer_Virtual_ReservedCapacityGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52660569/how-to-order-softlayer-virtual-reservedcapacitygroup))

To order Virtual Instance with reservedCapacityId is success.
but The Ordered VMs isn't shown.

we checked using this api.

```
https://IBM_ID:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/VirtualGuests.json
```

The return value gave the normal virtual instances except servers with reservedCapacityId.

is this api bug ? or we do use the other APIs ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is an api bug, it was reported to SoftLayer and I think it will be fixed soon, in the mean while I can recommend you to use [advancedSearch](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch/) method, following will return all virtual guest including those who are in a reserved capacity group.

```
POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch

{
    "parameters":[      
        "_objectType:SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest"
    ]
}
```

You can also try by using mask over the method [getReservedCapacityGroups](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getReservedCapacityGroups/) as following:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getReservedCapacityGroups?objectMask=mask[id,occupiedInstances[guest]]
```